# Next.Js : Change page without stop the audio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, routes, next.js

I'm new at ReactJS and now i'm using Next.js. 
Well, my project has a audio player at header. When site is load this audio player start automatically. And when I change the page the header statements are not change but music start over again. I try higher order component and shallow but these are not work.

So, how can add a player to header and the player wont start over when the page is change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature will be available from the v5.

Take a look at this pull request [3552](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/3552) and this thread [88](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/88).

Answer (score 0):

After researching lots days, I solved similar problem with this:

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts

Just make a HOC wrapped the whole _app and set what you want to do in the HOC.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30709112)